# eZ Publish 5: get absolute url of an image attribute of a class

Tags: symfony, twig, ezpublish

In eZ Publish 5, I have a class with an image attribute.

Within the twig template, I can get the relative url (e.g. '/var/site/storage/image/...') from the attribute parameters.

Now I need the absolute url. Which is the best way to get it?

Should I get the request information and append the base url to the relative one? Or there's a built in method for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like this:

```
{{ asset( ez_image_alias( content.getField( 'image' ), content.versionInfo, 'original' ).uri, absolute=true ) }}
```

ez_image_alias is used to get the image alias (obviously), and here we get the original variation.
Then we take the uri of the image alias, and pass it to symfony [asset](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets) function.

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this the correct answer.
Just don't forget to add some tests before such as :

Check if the content field you want to retrieve data from exists and if that field is not empty :

```
{% if content.fields['myFieldIdentifier'] is defined and not ez_is_field_empty(content, 'myFieldIdentifier') %}
    {# do the job #}
{% endif %}
```

Here's how the ImageFieldType is rendered by default :

```
{% block ezimage_field %}
{% spaceless %}
{% if not ez_is_field_empty( content, field ) %}
<figure {{ block( 'field_attributes' ) }}>
    {% set imageAlias = ez_image_alias( field, versionInfo, parameters.alias|default( 'original' ) ) %}
    <img src="{% if imageAlias %}{{ asset( imageAlias.uri ) }}{% else %}//:0{% endif %}"{% if imageAlias.width is defined %} width="{{ imageAlias.width }}"{% endif %}{% if imageAlias.height is defined %} height="{{ imageAlias.height }}"{% endif %} alt="{{ field.value.alternativeText }}" />
</figure>
{% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```